# Uneven number of subfloats on separate lines

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have 5 subfloats that I would like to distribute 3 on the top line and two udnerneath but equally spaced between the top 3. But `\\` doesn't seem to do anything between them. What do you sugges?

Gives this:

[image]

I.e. X X X

```
  X X

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\subfloat[Single window]{\label{fig:wind_single}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_single.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side]{\label{fig:wind_same}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_same.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, opposite sides]{\label{fig:wind_opposite}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_opposite.png}}\newline%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side with wings]{\label{fig:wind_wings}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_wings.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, adjacent walls]{\label{fig:wind_adjacent}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_adjacent.png}}%
}
\smallskip
\caption{Passive ventilation examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply get rid of the `\makebox` command (which in the new distribution won't do anything) and now you can use the standard line change command `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
%\makebox[\textwidth]{
\subfloat[Single window]{\label{fig:wind_single}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_single.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side]{\label{fig:wind_same}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_same.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, opposite sides]{\label{fig:wind_opposite}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_opposite.png}}\\%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side with wings]{\label{fig:wind_wings}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_wings.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, adjacent walls]{\label{fig:wind_adjacent}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_adjacent.png}}%
%}
\smallskip
\caption{Passive ventilation examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

I would also suggest you some other modifications to improve the result: since your subfigures are narrow, text for the subcaptions might result with usgly inter-word spacing; one way to prevent this is to set them \raggedright using

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
```

Another change is that you don't need to manually issue `\smallskip` to add some spacing between the object and the caption. If this is going to apply to all your figures, you can use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=<lenght>}
```

Here's the code with these modifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[figure]{skip=\bigskipamount}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\subfloat[Single window]{\label{fig:wind_single}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_single.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side]{\label{fig:wind_same}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_same.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, opposite sides]{\label{fig:wind_opposite}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_opposite.png}}\\%
\subfloat[Two openings, same side with wings]{\label{fig:wind_wings}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_wings.png}}\hspace{1em}%
\subfloat[Two openings, adjacent walls]{\label{fig:wind_adjacent}\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{./Figures/chapter2/wind_adjacent.png}}%
\caption{Passive ventilation examples}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice indeed! Just what I was looking for :) Thank you!

Comment: Incidentally, what do you recommend for spacing between subfloats? I.e manual spacing is ok, but sometimes I have a lot of figures and maybe latex has a more aesthetically pleasing idea?

Comment: @HCAI spacing between subfloats is a decision left for the author/publisher. Some of the criteria should be consistency and using a sensible value for separation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using `subcaption` rather than `subfig`, then maybe this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}
            \caption{A}
            \label{fig:A}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}
            \caption{B}
            \label{fig:B}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}
            \caption{C}
            \label{fig:C}
        \end{subfigure}\vskip 1em%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}
            \caption{D}
            \label{fig:D}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}
            \caption{E}
            \label{fig:E}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
        \begin{subfigure}{3cm}
            \hspace{\fill}
        \end{subfigure}\hspace{1em}%
        \caption{Passive ventilation examples}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For me, `subcaption` is preferable to `subfig`. Otherwise, you can use the same approach to add an empty 'subfigure' to the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering%
        \subfloat[Single window]{\label{fig:wind_single}\includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}}\hspace{1em}%
        \subfloat[Two openings, same side]{\label{fig:wind_same}\includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}}\hspace{1em}%
        \subfloat[Two openings, opposite sides]{\label{fig:wind_opposite}\includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}}\vskip 1em%
        \subfloat[Two openings, same side with wings]{\label{fig:wind_wings}\includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}}\hspace{1em}%
        \subfloat[Two openings, adjacent walls]{\label{fig:wind_adjacent}\includegraphics[demo,width=3cm, height=2cm]{}}\hspace{1em}%
        \subfloat{\hspace{3cm}}%
        \caption{Passive ventilation examples}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```